# Why does web2py display disabled input html when I use the checkbox widget?

Tags: python, html, web2py

I am learning web2py but am having some trouble. I have a one-to-many relationship as defined here:

```
db.define_table('dog',
    Field('name', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()))
db.define_table('person',
    Field('name', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('dogs', 'list:reference dog'))

db.person.dogs.widget=SQLFORM.widgets.checkboxes.widget
```

Where a dog has one owner, but an owner can have multiple dogs.

In my controller, I create a form which has a textfield for the person's name, and a list of dogs represented as checkboxes.

The controller code for the form creation is simply:

```
form = SQLFORM(db.person)   # rendered with {{=form}} in views
```

This works, but at the end of the list of checkboxes there is an odd text input which is marked as disabled:

```
<tr><td><input class="hidden" disabled="disabled" name="dogs" type="text" /></td></tr>
```

This isn't actually hidden, just greyed out.

I looked at the web2py source, and the checkbox widget is located in web2py.gluon.sqlhtml, but I'm having a hard time interpreting why it's appending this disabled input to the checkbox list.

Can anyone clarify why this disabled input is there or how to properly create this form without this problem?

Comment: I think it may be there just to show errors in case validation fails on that field (the error message will be appended after the hidden input field). It has `class="hidden"`, so it should be hidden if you have web2py.css or web2py.js loaded. If not, you can use a CSS rule to keep it hidden.

Comment: There is a .hidden definition in the web2py.css file. However the disabled input doesn't seem map to that css style in firebug. I'm not sure why it's not finding the correct css definition.

Comment: Yes, Anthony is right. The css was never loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anthony's comment was correct: I had forgotten to load the css file.